# How can i create a directory for each name that it's code belong to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm downloading files from links and i saved them so far in one directory.
But now i need to download each group of files to a specific directory.

This is the content of the first text file i added as existing item to my project. The countries names.

```
Europe
Alps
Benelux
Germany
Spain & Portugal
France
Greece
Italy
Poland
Scandinavia
Turkey
UK & Ireland
Russia
Baltic
Balkan
Romania & Bulgaria
Hungary
Africa
Algeria
Cameroon
CanaryIslands
Congo
CentralAfrica
Nigeria
Chad
Egypt
Ethiopia
Israel
Libya
Madagascar
Morocco
Namibia
SaudiArabia
Somalia
SouthAfrica
Sudan
Tanzania
Tunesia
WestAfrica
Zambia
```

And i have another text file that present each country code:

```
eu
alps
nl
de
sp
fr
gr
it
pl
scan
tu
gb
ru
bc
ba
se
hu
af
dz
cm
ce
cg
caf
ng
td
eg
et
is
ly
mg
mo
bw
sa
so
za
sd
tz
tn
wa
zm
```

Why the codes are important ? since each link is built inside with the country code not name. For example:

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271600&ir=true
```

So i know that in the link the part region=is meaning that the country code in this case is: 'is' (Israel).

So now i need to find all the links that have the code 'is' should be downloading to the directory of Israel.

Next when the links will be with other regions for example:

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271600&ir=true
```

So now the code tu is for the country Turkey so now every link with the code tu should be downloading to the Turkey directory.

So the first problem is how to connect between the code of the country in the links to the country name and then to download it to the correct country name directory that i allready created in the constructor ? I have all the countries names directories allready but i need somehow to connect between the codes(regions) in the links to the country name directory.

The second problem is that i'm making this downloads every 15 minutes. I will do it later with a timer. Every 15 minutes download the images again. But i don't want to delete or overwrite the old images the main idea is to save and keep the images. The problem is in each country every 15 minutes what sub paths should i create ? I mean what name to give each country sub paths every 15 minutes ?

I thought to create for each country a directory with the date and time range of the downloaded images but i'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Later i will want to be able to move between this directories of each country and that it will load the images to a pictureBox. The question is how i will be able to identify each directory that was downloaded every 15 minutes ?

The problem is not the downloading the program is working.
The two problems is with the directories.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Downloader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int countCompleted = 0;
        ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();

        List<string> newList = new List<string>();
        List<string> countryList = new List<string>();
        List<string> countriesPaths = new List<string>();

        private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ManageDirectories();

            lblDownloads.Text = "0";
            ei.Init();
            foreach (ExtractImages.Continent continent in ei.world.continents)
            {
                foreach (ExtractImages.Country country in continent.countries)
                {
                    if (country.name == "Israel")
                    {
                        foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                        {
                            countryList.Add(imageUri);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                        {
                            newList.Add(imageUri);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ManageDirectories()
        {
            string savedImagesPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            string mainPath = "Countries";
            mainPath = Path.Combine(savedImagesPath, mainPath);
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CountriesNames.txt");
            foreach(string path in lines)
            {
                string countryPath = Path.Combine(mainPath, path);
                if (!Directory.Exists(countryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
                }
                countriesPaths.Add(countryPath);
            }
            string[] countriesCodes = File.ReadAllLines("CountriesCodes.txt");
        }

        private void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            // Starts the download
            btnStart.Text = "Downloading...";
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            pbStatus.Visible = true;

            DownloadFile();
        }

        int count = 0;
        private void DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
                //string FileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                //          (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));


                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), countriesPaths[count] + ".gif");
                RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Downloading: ", Color.Red);
                RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, url, Color.Green);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                count++;
                return;
            }

            // End of the download
            btnStart.Text = "Download Complete";
            countCompleted = newList.Count;
            lblDownloads.Text = countCompleted.ToString();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            downloadFile(newList);
        }

        private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Downloading: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Red);
                // handle error scenario
                throw e.Error;
            }
            else
            {
                countCompleted--;
                lblDownloads.Text = countCompleted.ToString();
                RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Downloading: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // handle cancelled scenario
            }
            DownloadFile();
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            pbStatus.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countCompleted = countryList.Count;
            lblDownloads.Text = countCompleted.ToString();
            downloadFile(countryList);
        }

        public class RichTextBoxExtensions
        {
            public static void AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
                box.SelectionLength = 0;

                box.SelectionColor = color;
                box.AppendText(text);
                box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
            }
            public static void UpdateText(RichTextBox box, string find, string replace, Color? color)
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.Find(find, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
                box.SelectionLength = find.Length;
                box.SelectionColor = color ?? box.SelectionColor;
                box.SelectedText = replace;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void SortList()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code to read.. can you cut out the irrelevant parts?

Comment: This should probably be split up into multiple questions. For the first question: `File.ReadLines(file1).Zip(File.ReadLines(file2), (f1, f2) => new { DirectoryName = f1, CountryCode = f2 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two files are ordered as they are in the example you can create dictionary form code to full name the other way around.

```
var codes = new List<string>() { ..... }
var countries = new List<string> () { ....}
```

creating the dictionary will look like this

```
var codeToFullNameMap = codes
.Select((code, index) => index)
.ToDictionary(
    keySelector: index => codes[index].
    elementSelector: index => cointires[index]);
```

Then having the dictionary created you can access the full country name by its code.

```
var countryName = codeToFullNameMap["tu"];
```

About the second question. If the naming gives you enough information and by using the current date time it think it does, should be pefrectly fine.

My suggestion is to create Directory for the country code and sub folder for each download start time (including hours, minutes and seconds will be enough i guess).

```
TU // (main folder)
  -> 2017-01-26-18-50-10 // (subfolder 1)
      -> img#1
      -> img#2
  -> 2017-01-26-18-50-10 // (subfolder 2)
```

I am not sure about the third question. If your folder is called TU, this is enough to tell that the images are for Turkey, or i am missing something ? And each sub folder contains images downloaded at interval of 15 minutes from the last one.

Maybe if you share more specifics about the third question, where exactly you see the problem, for example you need to visualize the images in desktop application by countries ?

Comment: I'm getting error on the codeToFullNameMap. This is how it is in my code: var codeToFullNameMap = codes
.Select((code, index) => index)
.ToDictionary(
    keySelector: index => codes[index].
    valueSelector: index => countries[index]); First i had to fix the ToDictionary it wasn't written right. Second i'm getting error on the valueSelector not exist: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
The name 'valueSelector' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: This is working: Is that right way to do it ? var dictionary = codes.Zip(countries, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            var countryName = dictionary["tu"];

Comment: Yes its perfect ;]. About the dicionary issue, i've updated the answer.

Comment: How can i parse the country code from a link ? For example this is how a link looks like: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201701261545&ir=true and i need to parse the text between: region=HERE THE TEXT TO PARSE& for example in this case the code should be 'is' and if the link is: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201701261545&ir=true then the parsed text will be tu and if the link is http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=scan&time=201701261545&ir=true then the parsed part will be scan    Is there any way to do it using indexof and substring ?

Comment: Yes. Something like this. 

var startIndex = url.IndexOf("region=") + "region=".Length;                        

var length = url.IndexOf("&", startIndex) - startIndex;                             

var code = url.Substring(startIndex, length);

Answer (score 0):

Just use a generic dictionary to bind the country codes to the full name used in the directory path

```
Dictionary<string, string> countryCodeMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
   {"us", "United States"},
   {"is", "Isreal"}
   ...
};
```